# http / javascript / php post execution in C

Tags: php, javascript, html, c

I'm trying to figure out a way to call an html form from C, inject a bit of javascript, then submit the file and check the new URL (header from php) to make sure the form submitted correctly. Got any ideas???

Comment: Is C your only choice?  It might be easier to create something (say in Perl or Python) and call _that_ from C.

Comment: I don't understand your question (what do you mean by "Call an html form"?) Please improve your wording.

Comment: Sorry, I need to call the form "action" of the webpage from the program. The html form can be stored locally, and that might even make things easier, as I wouldn't need to use javascript injection to edit the fields, I could just edit the file using the program then call the action. 

The action php is on a remote server, it needs to execute the form action, then return the new URL/header to the program so I know it executed properly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

For an example see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html